# Is it possible to run Vagrant on Windows without relying on Cygwin rsync?

Tags: windows, vagrant

I installed Vagrant on Windows 10. But it won't run the VM because it complains that the installed Cygwin rsync is incompatible.

Right now, I have no need to synchronize files with Windows and so I don't think I need rsync.

Is it possible to tell Vagrant to turn this requirement / option off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use an [`override`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/configuration.html) in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
override.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```

Comment: I'm getting "undefined local variable or method `override` for main:Object (NameError)" if I try that

Comment: Have you checked the linked documentation? The example does not work in isolation, it needs to be wrapped in a `config` block.

Comment: OK. That's done it..